# querystring not getting in AWS Lambda integration proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[image: API Gateway]

[image: Lambda event]

With this setting, the variable is set to null no matter what querystring you enter in the URL.

Comment: where is the question ? please add more information

Comment: For example, even if I access /api/v1/member/test?q=1234, the querystringparameters will be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem caused by CloudFront caching setting.
I had solved to below setting in CloudFront.
Query String Forwarding and Caching: Forward All

Answer (score -1):

Here is two possible solutions

```
Api call: /api/v1/member?q=1234.
```

Lambda function : `event.queryStringParameters.q`

```
Api call: /api/v1/member/1234.
```

Lambda function: `event.pathParameters['proxy+']`

Comment: My problem is event.queryStringParamete is always null also on your first solution.